# Setting the Columns Editor position

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

This has driven me nuts for years. In the IDE, I have widened the Object Inspector (OI) to about 2-1/2" but the Columns Editor and Fields editor etc all pop-up where Borland thought I should have the width of the OI set.

I have to drag the editor off the OI every time I use them. Maybe I am getting old and grumpy, but it is beginning to wear me down.

Is there any way (hack even) I can set where these editors pop-up in D5? I don't care if it is exactly where I want them, just as long as it is not covering the OI. I tried the Ctrl-Close thing, but that did nothing.

Thanks

Comment: upgrade to a higher delphi version and never look back?

Comment: @whosrdaddy ...and that helps me how? I am 72 years old and program for pleasure. Been a programmer for probably longer than you have lived. Only an idiot would spend money on new software at my age. You must have been away from school the day they taught the "never assume" thing. I actually have D2007 but do not like it so I still use D5. Lead, follow or get out of the way.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Upgrade to the latest Delphi version and still suffer from columns/fields/collections editor popups appearing in strange places and being impossible to manage.

Comment: LOL @David -- thanks for that comment. I have just installed Lazerus and am finding my way around it. So far, so good. Maybe I can toss D5 and 2007.

Comment: Er, why would you choose to do that?